# Populating immutable lists "in a cycle"

Tags: list, f#, cycle

Within my F# learning process, I am trying to convert the following C# code with lists into its F# equivalent. I think it is easy to figure out what the code does - when *numberOfFilesList* is, for example, [2, 2, 4, 3, 1], then *endFilesToOpenList* is [2, 4, 8, 11, 12 ]. Both *numberOfFilesList* and *endFilesToOpenList* are needed further down the code flow. Here is the C# code:

```
List<int> endFilesToOpenList = new List<int>();
List<int> numberOfFilesList = new List<int>();
int sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < (high - low + 1); i++)
{
    //myDictionary is of type Dictionary<string, int> 
    string myKey = $@"Here is a string depending on (low + 1) and (low + i)";  
    myDictionary.TryGetValue(myKey, out int value);
    numberOfFilesList.Add(value);
    sum += value;
    endFilesToOpenList.Add(sum);
}
```

While populating the lists looks very simple and straightforward in this C# snippet, I cannot figure out a similarly simple equivalent in F#. **My question is: how to convert this C# code into a neat-looking F# code?**

I did try to make up something in F#. Although the code works, it seems to be very complicated, especially the code for populating *endFilesToOpenList*. I think there must be a better way to do it. My not very nice F# attempt is here:

```
let getOption j = 
    let i = j + 1  
    let myKey s1 s2 = $@"Here is a string depending on s1 and s2"   
    //myMap is of type Map<string, int>
    match i < (high - low + 1) with  
    | true  ->  
            match myMap.TryGetValue (myKey <| low + 1 <| low + i) with   
            | true, value -> Some(value, i)                                              
            | _  -> None    
    | false -> None  
let numberOfFilesList = List.unfold getOption (-1)
let sumAList list = List.fold(fun acc item -> acc + item) 0 list                                                       
let reducedList i = List.take i numberOfFilesList
let endFilesToOpenList = List.mapi(fun i item -> sumAList (reducedList <| i + 1)) numberOfFilesList
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do what you want:

```
let makeLists (myMap : Map<_, _>) =
    let numberOfFilesList =
        [
            for i = 0 to myMap.Count - 1 do
                match myMap |> Map.tryFind $"key{i}" with
                    | Some value -> yield value
                    | None -> ()
        ]
    let endFilesToOpenList =
        numberOfFilesList
            |> List.scan (+) 0
            |> List.skip 1
    numberOfFilesList, endFilesToOpenList
```

There are two main concepts here:

- Using a [list comprehension](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/F_Sharp_Programming/Lists#Using_List_Comprehensions) to generate `numberOfFilesList`.
- Then using `List.scan` to compute a running total of the values.

There are other ways to do it, of course, but I think this is closest in spirit to what you asked for. (Note that I simplified the key format somewhat to make the logic clearer. I think you should easily be able to enhance this part once you understand how the function works.)

You can test it like this:

```
let myMap =
    Map [
        "key0", 2
        "key1", 2
        "key2", 4
        "key3", 3
        "key4", 1
    ]        
let numberOfFilesList, endFilesToOpenList =
    makeLists myMap
printfn "numberOfFilesList: %A" numberOfFilesList
printfn "endFilesToOpenList: %A" endFilesToOpenList
```

Output matches your requirements:

```
numberOfFilesList: [2; 2; 4; 3; 1]
endFilesToOpenList: [2; 4; 8; 11; 12]
```

Comment: Technically speaking, the order of the lists in the test and in the test result should be reversed  "let numberOfFilesList, endFilesToOpenList  =  makeLists myMap", but everyone will understand anyway. Thanks for the concepts. Good inspiration for me.

Comment: Oops, will fix.